# Jquery cycle plug with wordpress, jquery is not defined?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am very new to wordpress and I am baffled.  I am trying to create a slide show and have followed all the directions I can find for adding jquery to wordpress.
In my `function.php` file I have added:

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}    

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

In my `header.php` I have:

```
<?php
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.cycle.js', get_bloginfo("stylesheet_directory").'/js/jquery.cycle.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('slideshow', get_bloginfo("stylesheet_directory") . '/js/slideshow.js');
    wp_head();
?>
```

My `slideshow.js` is:

```
jquery(document).ready(function($){
    jquery('#gallery').cycle('fade');
});
```

and in my *template* I have:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <p>
        <a href="http://bdf.serverplanet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/BD_Laurene1339467077747.jpg">
            <img src="http://bdf.serverplanet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/BD_Lauren_s.jpg" alt="Caption" />
        </a>
        <em>Brad &amp; Lauren</em>
    </p>
    <p>
        <a href="http://bdf.serverplanet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/BD_bike.jpg" target="_blank">
            <img src="http://bdf.serverplanet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/BD_bike_s.jpg" alt="Caption" />
        </a>
        <em>Biking on the Vineyard</em>
    </p>
    <a href="http://bdf.serverplanet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/bedcad.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="http://bdf.serverplanet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/bedcad_s.jpg" alt="Caption" /></a>
    <em>Brad and Cass</em>
    <a href="http://bdf.serverplanet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/brad11.jpg" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://bdf.serverplanet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/brad11_s.jpg" alt="Caption" />
    </a>
    <em>At the S.A.S.S. show</em>
    <a href="http://bdf.serverplanet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Brad_and_Alexis.jpg" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://bdf.serverplanet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/Brad_and_Alexis_s.jpg" alt="Caption" />
    </a>
    <em>With Alexis at a S.A.S.S. show</em>
</div>
```

When I'm trying to run the slideshow I am getting a "jquery is not defined" error in my `slideshow.js` file.
How do I fix this error and get my slideshow working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `jQuery` instead of `jquery` `Q` must be in uppercase, inisde `slideshow.js`

Comment: I added the ' after dot and I am still getting the error, did you see anything else that would cause it?

Comment: just a copy and paste mistake, now fixed.  I am still getting the jquery is not defined error though.  :(

Comment: I made the changes that you had suggested, and got a second error message, so I had to put back in the array('jquery'), and I am back to the jquery is no defined error only.

Comment: here is the page in question:  http://bdf.serverplanet.com/?page_id=132&preview=true&preview_id=132&preview_nonce=08d45e5c3f

Comment: @Jim i'm i glad i could help you

Comment: if you put your answer up I will up vote it and mark it as the one.